# Parse Nested JSON with Python/Pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, parsing

I would like to parse this json response:

```
{
   "count":2,
   "next":null,
   "previous":null,
   "results":[
      {
         "id":123,
         "type_vname":"Suspicious Remote Desktop",
         "category":"LATERAL MOVEMENT",
         "src_ip":"192.168.1.1",
         "state":"fixed",
         "description":null,
         "t_score":70,
         "c_score":70,
         "first_timestamp":"2017-12-13T18:51:22Z",
         "last_timestamp":"2017-12-13T18:51:22Z",
         "detection_detail_set":[
            {
               "id":1234567,
               "description":"Suspicious Remote Desktop",
               "dst_host_id":1234,
               "dst_ip":"192.168.1.1",
               "count":null,
               "count_pos":null,
               "dst_dns":null,
               "dst_port":80,
               "dst_geo":null,
               "proto":null,
               "first_timestamp":"2017-12-13T18:51:22Z",
               "last_timestamp":"2017-12-13T18:51:22Z",
               "total_bytes_sent":null,
               "total_bytes_rcvd":null,
               "url":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details"
            },
            {
               "id":89123456,
               "description":"Suspicious Remote Desktop",
               "dst_host_id":5678,
               "dst_ip":"192.168.1.1",
               "count":null,
               "count_pos":null,
               "dst_dns":null,
               "dst_port":80,
               "dst_geo":null,
               "proto":null,
               "first_timestamp":"2017-12-13T18:50:18Z",
               "last_timestamp":"2017-12-13T18:50:18Z",
               "total_bytes_sent":null,
               "total_bytes_rcvd":null,
               "url":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details"
            }
         ],
         "dns_set":[

         ],
         "relayed_comm_set":[

         ],
         "sensor_luid":"abc1pdj",
         "summary":{
            "internal_targets":1,
            "anomalous_events":2,
            "probable_owner":"user"
         },
         "host":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details",
         "url":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details",
         "tags":[

         ],
         "targets_key_asset":false,
         "triage_rule_id":null
      },
      {
         "id":1235,
         "type_vname":"Suspicious Remote Desktop",
         "category":"LATERAL MOVEMENT",
         "src_ip":"192.168.1.2",
         "state":"fixed",
         "description":null,
         "t_score":70,
         "c_score":70,
         "first_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:11:46Z",
         "last_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:11:46Z",
         "detection_detail_set":[
            {
               "id":123445,
               "description":"Suspicious Remote Desktop",
               "dst_host_id":4958,
               "dst_ip":"192.168.1.2",
               "count":null,
               "count_pos":null,
               "dst_dns":null,
               "dst_port":80,
               "dst_geo":null,
               "proto":null,
               "first_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:11:46Z",
               "last_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:11:46Z",
               "total_bytes_sent":null,
               "total_bytes_rcvd":null,
               "url":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details"
            },
            {
               "id":1274857,
               "description":"Suspicious Remote Desktop",
               "dst_host_id":15423,
               "dst_ip":"192.168.1.2",
               "count":null,
               "count_pos":null,
               "dst_dns":null,
               "dst_port":80,
               "dst_geo":null,
               "proto":null,
               "first_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:11:46Z",
               "last_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:11:46Z",
               "total_bytes_sent":null,
               "total_bytes_rcvd":null,
               "url":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details"
            },
            {
               "id":137847,
               "description":"Suspicious Remote Desktop",
               "dst_host_id":93238,
               "dst_ip":"192.168.1.2",
               "count":null,
               "count_pos":null,
               "dst_dns":null,
               "dst_port":80,
               "dst_geo":null,
               "proto":null,
               "first_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:10:53Z",
               "last_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:10:53Z",
               "total_bytes_sent":null,
               "total_bytes_rcvd":null,
               "url":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details"
            },
            {
               "id":2376849874,
               "description":"Suspicious Remote Desktop",
               "dst_host_id":15423,
               "dst_ip":"192.168.1.2",
               "count":null,
               "count_pos":null,
               "dst_dns":null,
               "dst_port":80,
               "dst_geo":null,
               "proto":null,
               "first_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:10:53Z",
               "last_timestamp":"2017-12-11T19:10:53Z",
               "total_bytes_sent":null,
               "total_bytes_rcvd":null,
               "url":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details"
            }
         ],
         "dns_set":[

         ],
         "relayed_comm_set":[

         ],
         "sensor_luid":"abcery",
         "summary":{
            "internal_targets":1,
            "anomalous_events":4,
            "probable_owner":"user"
         },
         "host":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details",
         "url":"https://192.168.1.2/api/detection_details",
         "tags":[

         ],
         "targets_key_asset":false,
         "triage_rule_id":null
      }
   ]
}
```

To a dataframe so I can to_csv to a .csv file with the following headers for the json data:

```
count
next
previous
results_id
results_type_vname
results_category
results_src_ip
results_state
results_description
results_t_score
results_c_score
results_first_timestamp
results_last_timestamp
results_dns_set
results_relayed_comm_set
results_sensor_luid
results_host
results_url
results_tags
results_targets_key_asset
results_triage_rule_id
summary_internal_targets
summary_anomalous_events
summary_probable_owner
detection_id
detection_description
detection_dst_host_id
detection_dst_ip
detection_count
detection_count_pos
detection_dst_dns
detection_dst_port
detection_dst_geo
detection_proto
detection_first_timestamp
detection_last_timestamp
detection_total_bytes_sent
detection_total_bytes_rcvd
detection_url
```

I have searched SO and wrote some of my own code here (json response is in 'data'):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = json_normalize(data=df['results'], record_path='detection_detail_set', 
                            meta=['category', 'id'], record_prefix='results_', errors='ignore')

df = df.head()

df.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False)
```

I get the following headers (with data) in the response:

```
results_count
results_count_pos
results_description
results_dst_dns
results_dst_geo
results_dst_host_id
results_dst_ip
results_dst_port
results_first_timestamp
results_id
results_last_timestamp
results_proto
results_total_bytes_rcvd
results_total_bytes_sent
results_url
category
id
```

I feel like I am halfway there. I have tried several combinations and advice from other SO posts to get the remaining data. Nothing has worked thus far. I know the issue I am encountering is due to the nesting, just need to find a way to get the desired result. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the right idea, just need to merge the `results` layer with the unpacked `detection` layer:

```
results = (json_normalize(data=df["results"], errors="ignore")
           .drop("detection_detail_set", 1)
           .add_prefix("results_"))
results.columns = results.columns.str.replace("results_summary\\.", "results_")

detection = json_normalize(data=df['results'], meta=['category', 'id'], 
                           record_path='detection_detail_set',  
                           record_prefix="detection_", errors='ignore')

master = results.merge(detection, how="left", 
                       left_on=["results_id", "results_category"], 
                       right_on=["id", "category"])

master.columns
Index(['results_c_score', 'results_category', 'results_description',
       'results_dns_set', 'results_first_timestamp', 'results_host',
       'results_id', 'results_last_timestamp', 'results_relayed_comm_set',
       'results_sensor_luid', 'results_src_ip', 'results_state',
       'results_anomalous_events', 'results_internal_targets',
       'results_probable_owner', 'results_t_score', 'results_tags',
       'results_targets_key_asset', 'results_triage_rule_id',
       'results_type_vname', 'results_url', 'detection_count',
       'detection_count_pos', 'detection_description', 'detection_dst_dns',
       'detection_dst_geo', 'detection_dst_host_id', 'detection_dst_ip',
       'detection_dst_port', 'detection_first_timestamp', 'detection_id',
       'detection_last_timestamp', 'detection_proto',
       'detection_total_bytes_rcvd', 'detection_total_bytes_sent',
       'detection_url', 'category', 'id'],
      dtype='object')
```